# Reference an image in add-on from css

Tags: css, firefox-addon

I use Add-On SDK, and I have a `data` folder with both a `css` and a `img` folders.
The `css` folder contains a CSS stylesheet injected from the content-script in a page (top or iframe).
I'd like to reference images, located in the `img` folder, from the CSS (background attribute).

Is there any way to achieve this without using a full-path `resource://<extname>/data/img/icon.png` ?

Comment: That's the only way. Well the other way is to register a manifest file then use a full chrome:// path. Full paths are only way, relative paths dont work.

Comment: Thanks. I should have given more info on the context, i was talking about a firefox add-on (using high-level APIs in Add-on SDK).

Comment: Yea you have to use full path, no other way.